# R delete first and last x % of rows

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 3 ID variables, then several values for each ID.

```
user   Log Pass  Value
2       2   123     342
2       2   123     543
2       2   123     231
2       2   124     257
2       2   124     342
4       3   125     543
4       3   125     231
4       3   125     257
4       3   125     342
4       3   125     543
4       3   125     231
4       3   125     257
4       3   125     543
4       3   125     231
4       3   125     257
4       3   125     543
4       3   125     231
4       3   125     257
4       3   125     543
4       3   125     231
4       3   125     257
```

The start and end of each set of values is sometimes noisy, and I want to be able to delete the first few values. Unfortunately the number of values varies significantly, but it is always the first and last 20% of values that are noisy.

I want to delete the first 20% of rows, with a minimum of 1 row deleted.

So for instance if there are 20 values for user 2 log 2 pass 123 I want to delete the first and last 4 rows. If there are only 3 values for the ID variable I want to delete the first and last row.

The resulting dataset would be:

```
user   Log Pass  Value
2       2   123     543
4       3   125     543
4       3   125     231
4       3   125     257
4       3   125     543
4       3   125     231
4       3   125     257
4       3   125     543
4       3   125     231
```

I've tried fiddling around with nrow but I struggle to figure out how to reference the % of rows by id variable.

Thanks.

Jonathan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following can do it.

**DATA.**

```
dat <-
structure(list(user = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Log = c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), Pass = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 124L, 124L, 125L, 125L, 
125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 
125L, 125L, 125L), Value = c(342L, 543L, 231L, 257L, 342L, 543L, 
231L, 257L, 342L, 543L, 231L, 257L, 543L, 231L, 257L, 543L, 231L, 
257L, 543L, 231L, 257L)), .Names = c("user", "Log", "Pass", "Value"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

**CODE.**

```
fun <- function(x, p = 0.20){
    n <- nrow(x)
    m <- max(1, round(n*p))
    inx <- c(seq_len(m), n - seq_len(m) + 1)
    x[-inx, ]
}

result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, dat$user), fun))
row.names(result) <- NULL
result
#   user Log Pass Value
#1     2   2  123   543
#2     2   2  123   231
#3     2   2  124   257
#4     4   3  125   342
#5     4   3  125   543
#6     4   3  125   231
#7     4   3  125   257
#8     4   3  125   543
#9     4   3  125   231
#10    4   3  125   257
#11    4   3  125   543
#12    4   3  125   231
#13    4   3  125   257
```

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this help?

For a dataframe `df`:

```
df[-c(1:floor(nrow(df)*0.2), (1+ceiling(nrow(df)*0.8)):nrow(df)),]
```

Just removing the first and last 20%, taking the upper and lower values so that for smaller data frame you keep some of the information:

```
> df<-data.frame(a=1:100)
> df[-c(1:floor(nrow(df)*0.2),(1+ceiling(nrow(df)*0.8)):nrow(df)),]

 [1] 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
[31] 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80


> df<-data.frame(1:3)
> df[-c(1:floor(nrow(df)*0.2),(1+ceiling(nrow(df)*0.8)):nrow(df)),]

[1] 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `dplyr`...

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% group_by(user, Log, Pass) %>% 
  filter(n()>2) %>% #remove those with just two elements or fewer
  slice(max(2, 1+ceiling(n()*0.2)):min(n()-1, floor(0.8*n())))

df2
   user   Log  Pass Value
1     2     2   123   543
2     4     3   125   543
3     4     3   125   231
4     4     3   125   257
5     4     3   125   543
6     4     3   125   231
7     4     3   125   257
8     4     3   125   543
9     4     3   125   231
```

Comment: What an excellent solution! I have been avoiding dplyr because it looks confusing but I think this might make me learn it. 

To other contributors - your solutions looked great too but as a beginning R coder it would have taken me a long time to figure out how to add more than one ID variable. This answer had all three id variables in it and ready to go.

Comment: @JonathanNolan Yes, there are some things `dplyr` and `tidyr` are really useful for - grouping is one of them.  I recommend the RStudio cheat sheet as a handy introduction to them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea using base R that returns the row indices of each user to keep and then subsets on these indices.

```
idx <- unlist(lapply(split(seq_along(dat[["user"]]), dat[["user"]]), function(x) {
                     tmp <- max(1, ceiling(.2 * length(x)))
                     tail(head(x, -tmp), -tmp)}),
              use.names=FALSE)
```

`split(seq_along(dat[["user"]]), dat[["user"]])` returns a list of the rows for each user. `lapply` loops through these rows, calculating the number of rows to drop from each end with `split(seq_along(dat[["user"]]), dat[["user"]])`, and then dropping them with `tail(head(x, -tmp), -tmp)})`. Since `lapply` returns a named list, this is unlisted and the names are dropped.

This returns

```
idx
 2  3  4 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

Now subset

```
dat[idx,]
   user Log Pass Value
2     2   2  123   543
3     2   2  123   231
4     2   2  124   257
10    4   3  125   543
11    4   3  125   231
12    4   3  125   257
13    4   3  125   543
14    4   3  125   231
15    4   3  125   257
16    4   3  125   543
17    4   3  125   231
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the offset for what you want to retain:

```
rem <- ceiling( nrow( x ) * .2 ) + 1
```

Then take out the records you don-t want:

```
dat <- dat[ rem : ( nrow( dat ) - rem ), ]
```